# React Three Fiber OrbitControls Initial zoom wider

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, orbitcontrols

I am working on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sutherland-jvg9pn?file=/src/index.js) to do practice with React Three Fiber.

My question with the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sutherland-jvg9pn?file=/src/index.js) is that i do not really understand how i can set the initial zoom way wider in `OrbitControls` in order that i can see more small stars?

This is the relevant code where i think i need to pass the zoom values

```
  <OrbitControls
    enableZoom={true}
    enablePan={true}
    enableRotate={true}
  />
```

I was digging in the official website to understand what is actually needed for `OrbitControls` to configure the initial zoom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the camera's initial position further away. In three.js you would do:

```
camera.position.set(x, y, z); // The point where you want the camera
controls.update();
```

Seems to work in this demo as well. Try e.g. moving away on the x axis:

```
  <PerspectiveCamera
    makeDefault
    position={[500, 0.9, 1.8]}
    fov={60}
    zoom={0.9}
  />
```

See sandbox [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-noether-j0z29i?file=/src/index.js).